# Logback is only logging to console, not working on file

Tags: logback

I'm trying redirect all my logs to a file but it's not working. It only displays on console.

Here is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/Users/Plac/Development/logs/detc.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/Users/Plac/Development/logs/detc.log_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.detc.resources" level="INFO" />

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

What is wrong on my configuration?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration looks fine. I would suggest **two things**:

1. Check the file permissions, and ownerships on `/Users/Plac/Development/logs/detc.log`, right up to the root.
2. Make sure that the logger is using the same config file. To be certain, delete/Move other instances of config file from other directories like bin.

Comment: Well, there can be many places that it can be sourced/read from, and the config found first in class path is used. Thus, to avoid any confusions we would keep only one copy.

Comment: fixed it. need to add jboss-deployment-structure.xml. :)